# Ruby sass and undefined variables in imported files

Tags: ruby, sass

I have two scss files in a folder scss which will be included into a primary app.scss file.  All of these are transpiled to corresponding css files in /css folder:

scss/global/swatches.scss:

```
$swatch-bg: rgba(30,30,45,1);
```

scss/global/panels.scss

```
.panel {
    background-color: $swatch-bg;   
}
```

And then they are both included in my app.scss file:

scss/app.scss:

```
@import 'global/swatches.scss';
@import 'global/panels.scss';
```

and then I run:

```
sass --watch scss:css
```

This correctly creates all expected files inthe  css/folder.

However, if I now modify panels.scss which contains a reference to a variable (imported in app.scss) the watcher complains it can't find the variable.  But if I edit and save app.scss after, it will correctly compile and the variable is correctly parsed too.

So it seems, if I edit app.scss, any variables defined in any of the imported files will be available to subsequent imported files when sass is compiling.  But this is only true when editing app.scss.

How can I get it to compile correctly without having to add the same imports to each file?  Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Comment: The answer will be based on the capabilities of `> sass --watch` and how it loads and reloads code. My guess is that it is hooking into file changes and you will have to always save `app.scss` when making changes to files imported by that file.

Comment: @Chiperific it turns out renaming the the imported files to partials (filenames with underscore prefixes) resolves the problem.

Comment: You should be able to post your solution and accept it as the answer (maybe after a delay) to help the next weary traveler.

Comment: Ruby Sass should no longer be used, and will no longer be receiving any updates. Use LibSass

Comment: @Brad Thanks, but it seems LibSass is now also deprecated according to their site and DartSass should be used instead, will consider this for future projects but for the meantime Ruby Sass will suffice for the project I am developing

Comment: @MusaffarPatel yep you are right. My mistype. Especially since I use SASS every day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by using partials instead in the following manner:

Firstly, rename all my imports to include a prefix, for example:

```
global/_swatches.scss
```

and then in my main file (app.scss) import is as follows:

```
@import 'global/swatches';
```

Notice the lack of the underscore and .scss file extension